# changing data from context consumer doesn't change the displayed data (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm implementing a shopping cart, that obviously will have a button to add more products. I implemented the cart context and the functionality works fine, but when I increase the number of the products to purchase it doesn't change the number displayed. What could my issue would be?

Here is my code for the context consumer

```
    render() {
    return (
        <CartContext.Consumer>
            {
                (cartContext =>{
                    const {addProduct} = cartContext
                        return(
                            <div>
                                <h1 key={this.props.product.itemId}> {this.state.product.name} </h1>
                                <button onClick={() => {addProduct(this.props.product.itemId)}}> Add </button>
                                <h4>{this.props.product.qty}</h4>
                                <hr/>
                            </div>
                        )
                })
            }
        </CartContext.Consumer>
    )
}
```

Comment: The quantity (from the looks of it) is a prop, passed in from a parent. Even though you may be adding products and keeping track of them in the context, are you changing the props that get passed down too? Perhaps the context should contain a list of products, so you could do {cartProducts.length} ?

Comment: @rrd the props are acutally came from a container component to that has a context consumer